# Unity3d - Is there any whay to add a script to all colliders automatically

Tags: unity-game-engine, automation

I'm making a library where it would be beneficial to add a script to all objects with a collider automatically. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Yes, there is a way of course: 1. Find all colliders 2. add component

Comment: @derHugo
I mean that it does it automatically when adding the library without any interaction.

Comment: Then do this e.g. in [`[InitializeOnLoadMethod]`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/InitializeOnLoadMethodAttribute.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think one can do something like this:

```
foreach(var go in GameObject.FindObjectsOfType(typeof(GameObject)))
{
    if (!go.TryGetComponent<ScriptName>() && go.TryGetComponent<Collider>())
    {
        go.AddComponent<ScriptName>();
    }
}
```

You can make it look better with LINQ of course, but I left it as is for the sake of clarity.